# GDB debugging arguments passed through newlib

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, arm, newlib

I am trying to use newlib on a TI CC2538 ARM Cortex M3 part. The objective is to use printf for debugging messages and I've actually got that working. However the system will segfault after a number of messages (ARM calls that a HardFault) and I have no idea why.

I used GDB to get the following stack trace:

```
(gdb) bt full
#0  FaultISR () at src/startup_gcc.c:307
        fault_stat = 0x8200
        hfault_stat = 0x40000000
        mmfault_stat = 0xfffffff8
        busfault_stat = 0xfffffff8
        buf = "\000\000\000\000\371\377\377\377\026\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\n\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\b\f\000 \002\000\000\000\060\r\000 \320\f\000 \002\000\000\000\303w \000\000\000\000\000w?\032\000\360\v\000 \360\v\000 \002\000\000\000\027\000\000\000\003\000\000\000\277\022\035\000\b\f\000 \b\f\000  \r\000 \027\000\000\000\f\000\000\000\371\377\377\377T\025\000 a\217 \000\r\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\210\r\000 s\263\""
#1  <signal handler called>
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x002076dc in strlen ()
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x0020494a in _svfprintf_r ()
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x002045aa in _vsnprintf_r ()
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x002045fe in vsnprintf ()
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00200fa8 in ws_debug_vfprintf (f=STDERR, fmt=0x208f24 "Received a packet of length %u\n", args=...) at src/os/ws_debug.c:220
        len = 0x27
        buf = 0x20001538 "DBG src/net/mac/packet_scheduler.c:123 "
#7  0x00200f4e in ws_debug_fprintf (f=STDERR, fmt=0x208f24 "Received a packet of length %u\n") at src/os/ws_debug.c:201
        args = {__ap = 0x20000e50 <pui32Stack+440>}
#8  0x00201dea in packet_scheduler_timer () at src/net/mac/packet_scheduler.c:123
        phy_len = 0xd
        pkt = 0x8ef6
        fcf = 0x0
        buf = 0x20001738 "\200\220"
#9  0x00200c32 in ws_timer_update () at src/os/ws_timer.c:156
        ptr = 0x20001728
        new = 0x20001728
#10 0x002005c2 in main () at src/main.c:143
No locals.
```

As you can see, the newlib parts (#2 - #5) don't have any information with them making it hard to debug. I assume this is because newlib was stripped of debugging symbols, however I recompiled newlib and get the same result.

I am running Arch linux using the toolchain available in the official repos.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-none-eabi
Configured with: /build/arm-none-eabi-gcc/src/gcc-5-20150519/configure --target=arm-none-eabi --prefix=/usr --with-sysroot=/usr/arm-none-eabi --with-native-system-header-dir=/include --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-plugins --disable-decimal-float --disable-libffi --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-threads --disable-tls --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-system-zlib --with-newlib --with-headers=/usr/arm-none-eabi/include --with-python-dir=share/gcc-arm-none-eabi --with-gmp --with-mpfr --with-mpc --with-isl --with-libelf --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-pkgversion='Arch Repository' --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --with-multilib-list=armv6-m,armv7-m,armv7e-m,armv7-r
Thread model: single
gcc version 5.1.0 (Arch Repository)
```

-

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb -v
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9.1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --target=arm-none-eabi".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
```

I manually built the newlib package using the Arch Build System (ABS) and I think that the debugging symbols should be included (the function names show up in GDB. Is that enough?)

Any ideas on what I can try next?

## Edit

I have revised the output so the fault status registers are actually readable.

Here's the decoded output:

```
fault_stat: 0x8200 (BFARV, PRECISE)
hfault_stat: 0x40000000 (FORCED)
busfault_stat: 0xfffffff8 (valid FAULTADDR)
```

Interpreting that, we've had a bus fault exception with the address of the offending instruction stored in FAULTADDR. I'm not sure what caused the CPU to try and call 0xffffff8 but I'm pretty sure that will have caused the problem.

Comment: Are you sure this is due to memory access failure? Unless you enable/configure the MPU and run in unprivileged mode, there will be no protection apart from accesses to nonexistent memory/registers. A hardfault can have other reasons, too. Also printing the faultstat registers (bitfields) in decimal is only for the very, very, very, .... , very best assembler geeks transparent. We normal geeks still require some base-2 format like oct or hex at least. Even better: you check the actual flags yourself and ask more specific.

Comment: @Olaf I've updated the description to include more information. It looks as though PC gets corrupted somehow, but I might be interpreting the results wrong.

Comment: Well, As a hint, you should check your code for buffer overflow. Could be very well some data allocated on the stack overflowing into the return frame. That's all I will given you here, Get comfortable with the debugger yourself; youu'll need that anyway. This question is clearly out of bounds; this is no debugging help site. Please understand.

Comment: Just one note: that hardfault appears to be an escalated fault from somewhere else. My, I had something similar, but cannot remember whar that was back then.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a problem with newlib. I switched to newlib-nano and the problem seems to have gone away. I was missing my own _sbrk implementation, so it's possible the stack got overrun by the heap. However I wasn't allocating that much memory in the state the error occurs.

Comment: "The problem **seems** ..." is always very bad. As you do not know if that is just undefined behaviour that lets you get along with that. You better be sure what the problem is. Why not just step through with the debugger and check where the fault occurs? IIRC newlib is open source, For the symbols (I just had some sleep, so brain works better now), you might check your linker script if all relevant sections are included in the output.

Comment: How do you figure the stack size is 0x8000? The 0x8200 is the value in the fault status register (BFARV and PRECISE). FYI, the stack is set to 256 bytes (increasing this to 1024 bytes didn't help).

Comment: @Olaf I think bigger things are at play here. Turns out I had an interrupt calling a function which then called malloc. Likely malloc was screwing with things which printf was in the middle os using. While I'm not 100% certain this is the problem it is a very likely candidate. I'm in the process of removing the reliance of malloc in that particular code path.

Comment: @Olaf I've been stepping through with the debugger for a long time without finding anything interesting. It doesn't happen consistently which is why I suspected interrupts were a part of the problem. I'm not sure how to debug such a situation with my debugger.

Comment: IIRC you have to provide some helpers for newlib to be able to send/receive data (putc/getc at least or so). Maybe there is a problem? An interrupt handler calling malloc() sound by itself like an invitaition to trouble (unless you have depterministic (real-time) and interrupt-safe memory management, but I would not call that "malloc()" then).

Comment: Debugging interrupt handler is a pain, I tell you! However, you can use breakpoint/watchpoint at certain places and inspect the state. Not sure about the TI, but the STM32 can halt certain peripherals when the CPU has stopped for debugging. There might also be some registers in the DWT module which might help.